# How to evaluate 3 subsets in R

Tags: r

I have 3 subsets with an id property. How can I check if one specific id is present in all 3 subsets?

And then I would like to store this id.

Here an Example:

```
Subset1$ID = 1, 2, 3
Subset2$ID = 1, 3, 4
Subset3$ID = 1, 5, 6
```

So the result here would be 1.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> Subset1 <- data.frame('ID'=c(1,2,3))
> Subset2 <- data.frame('ID'=c(1,3,4))
> Subset3 <- data.frame('ID'=c(1,5,6))
> Reduce(intersect, list(Subset1$ID,Subset2$ID,Subset3$ID))
[1] 1
> common_id <-  Reduce(intersect, list(Subset1$ID,Subset2$ID,Subset3$ID))
> common_id
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`unique(merge(Subset1$ID,merge(Subset2$ID,Subset3$ID))[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
t <- table(c(Subset1, Subset2, Subset3)) == 3
names(t[which(t)])
```